# When does Spark send data to different executors after I created a DataFrame with RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm trying to construct a DataFrame from a list of data, then write it as parquet files:

```
dataframe = None
while True:
    data_list = get_data_list() # this function would return a list of data, about 1 million rows
    rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(data_list, 20)
    if dataframe:
        dataframe.union(sparkSession.createDataFrame(data=rdd))
    else:
        dataframe = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data=rdd)
    
    if some_judgement:
        break
dataframe.write.parquet('...')
```

But I found the driver would fail with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` after a few cycles. If I increase the `driver-memory` or decrease the number of cycles in the loop, this exception stops occurring. So I guess even if I created an RDD, the data is still stored in the driver. So when will the data be sent to executors ? I want to decrease the memory usage of the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check the logs and see where the exception is happening (Either at driver or executor)? If its happening at driver -> can you increase driver memory to 8 or 10 GB and see if it gets succeeded ?

Also I would suggest to set some higher values for memoryOverHead params.

```
spark.driver.memoryOverhead
spark.executor.memoryOverhead
```

Comment: Hi @Shane thanks for your suggestion, I've tried your way to increase the driver memory and update my questionExpandingng the driver memory could solve this problem but I don't want to increase memory infinitely to solve this problem. Do you know what else I could try?

Comment: you could try setting memory overhead params i shared. Ideally the dataset size matters and your infra should have appropriate resources to handle it.